# Modifying CSS/JS to stay expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been playing around with our question form for a while, and am having trouble figuring out how to tweak its effect. http://rayku.com/start

http://rayku.com/ss/2012-02-23_03-26-56.png

Something really annoying is that if I don't type anything in the question box, and I click on anything on the form below it, it will go back to its original collapsed state.

Do you know how I can modify the CSS or JS so that it will only collapse if I click outside of the combined form area

[image]

WHILE there is no text that is typed in the question field?

Thanks!

Comment: how did you accomplish the 3d effect on scroll down?

Comment: Have a look at this jquery plugin: http://dev.jonraasch.com/scrolling-parallax/docs there are some cool examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should change:

```
mainQuestion.focus(function(){
```

to

```
mainQuestion.keyup(function(){
```

so you make sure that the person has entered a question and you can hide the form if they don't.

**EDIT**

change your code to:

```
//store object in var for efficiency
var mainQuestion = $('.main-question input');
var initialValue = 'Start typing your question here';

mainQuestion.focus(function(){
    //blank out field on focus
    if(mainQuestion.val() == initialValue){
        mainQuestion.val('');
    }
});

mainQuestion.keyup(function(){
    //animate opening here
    $('#register-form').stop().animate({top:"-130px"},1000);
    $('#register-block').slideDown();
});

mainQuestion.blur(function(){
    //check to see if user has typed anything in
    if((mainQuestion.val() == initialValue) || !mainQuestion.val().length){
        //reset value
        mainQuestion.val(initialValue);
        //animate closing here
        $('#register-form').stop().animate({top:"0px"},500);
        $('#register-block').slideUp(); 
    }
});
```

Comment: That works, however its a bit confusing, as you're looking at the text box suddenly where you're focusing has moved up.

Comment: I really like this, thanks. However, it's bugging out the placeholder effect for the question text field (see live site). Do you have any ideas on that? Thanks!

Comment: @Donny I have edited my answer with the complete code, check if that resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable to test if the mouse is over the form with hover.

```
 var isOverForm = false;

 $('#myformWrap').hover(function(){
     isOverForm = (!isOverForm);
 });

 isTextBlank = //test if input is empty or initial value script

 $('body').click(function(){

       if(!isOverForm && isTextBlank){
              //hide form script
       }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest changing this:

```
mainQuestion.blur(function(){
    //check to see if user has typed anything in
    if((mainQuestion.val() == initialValue) || !mainQuestion.val().length ){
        //reset value
        mainQuestion.val('Start typing your question here');
        //animate closing here
        $('#register-form').animate({top:"0px"},1000);
        $('#register-block').slideUp(); 
    }
});
```

To something like this

```
mainQuestion.blur(function(){
    // check to see if any of the other text boxes are focussed
    var focTF = $('#register-block-fields input:focus');
    if(focTF.length > 0){
      //check to see if user has typed anything in
      if((mainQuestion.val() == initialValue) || !mainQuestion.val().length ){
          //reset value
          mainQuestion.val('Start typing your question here');
          //animate closing here
        $('#register-form').animate({top:"0px"},1000);
        $('#register-block').slideUp(); 
      }
    }
});
```

That will make sure it doesn't close if another text box is focussed. However, you might have to also run the same function on the `.blur()` event of `#register-block-fields` as well so that the box does go away eventually.